# AP Statistics Problem 2012: Confidence Intervals

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

In a survey of 900 people in the US a journalist says that 60% of people support a new law. If the margin of error is 2.7% for the percentage, what is the level of confidence? I figure that the number of positive responses range from 564 to 526 but where do I go from there?

Comment: If this is self-study you need to say so and add the tag, read its wiki and tell us how far you have got.

Comment: Hint: mean and standard deviation -- normal approximation to the binomial.

Answer (score 0):

The confidence interval for a proportion is $$\hat{p} \, \pm \, z_{\alpha/2} \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p} (1-\hat{p})}{n}}$$

The problem provides $\hat{p}=0.6$, $n=900$, and margin of error $=0.027$ (which is the entire quantity to the right of $\pm$). From those, you can compute what $z_{\alpha/2}$ you are dealing with. Then, you can determine the confidence level.